# Jest: Can't use default exports?

Tags: testing, jestjs, es6-modules, babel-jest

I'm having a weird issue where Jest does not seem to work when using `export default` on a module.

I've created a sample repo to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/syropian/jest-test

The gist of it is, given this module:

```
const a = {
  greet () {
    return 'Hello World'
  }
}

const b = {
  foo () {
    return 'bar'
  }
}

export default {
  a,
  b
}
```

This works:

```
import myModule from '../src'

describe('My module', () => {
  it('works if I import the whole module', () => {
    const greeting = myModule.a.greet()
    const foo = myModule.b.foo()
    expect(greeting).toBe('Hello World')
    expect(foo).toBe('bar')
  })
})
```

but this results in `a` and `b` being `undefined`:

```
import { a, b } from '../src'

describe('My module', () => {
  it('works if I import individual exports', () => {
    const greeting = a.greet()
    const foo = b.foo()
    expect(greeting).toBe('Hello World')
    expect(foo).toBe('bar')
  })
})
```

See the provided repo for `.babelrc` setup, etc.

Using node `7.3.0`